# Performance comparison for Java vs JSP's JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Many times we can handle a piece of code in Java as well as in JSP with JSTL, for instance a simple comparison and setting the value appropriately on the basis of the comparison.

Considering best practices and performance, which alternative should we prefer? Are both the same from a performance point of view?

P.S. Not talking about Java scriptlets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of JSTL and any JSP server tags for that matter, was to get Java code out of the JSP.

The JSP is a presentation technology used for the "view" part of your application. It should only handle presentation logic. But because adding Java code in scriptlets was so easy, a lot of developers started adding business logic inside the JSP. You thus end up with a poorly testable application (as @Steve C commented in his answer) because you have poor [separation of concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98734/what-is-separation-of-concerns). This in turn results in a big maintainability mess.

So server tags replace [the use of scriptlets (a practice frowned upon)](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/WhyNotUseScriptlets) and force you to have the business code where it belongs: in Java classes with very well defined behaviors.

That was for the intro, now to get back to your question...

Using a server tag takes indeed more code to execute than just doing the same thing in plain Java code because there is an entire [lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616064/jsp-tag-lifecycle) the container puts the tag through in order to get an output from it. It's slower, yes, but most of the time it's irrelevant. When thinking about performance you have to keep in mind [the rules of optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesOfOptimization):

> First Rule Of Optimization - Don't.
>   Second Rule Of Optimization - Don't... yet.
>   Profile Before Optimizing

As for best practices, you should not sacrifice readability and maintainability of the code by splitting it between the Java classes and the JSP just because you can. As I said in the beginning, JSP is for presentation, not business logic. Related code should stick together not be scattered all over the different layers of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to keep your JSPs as logic free as you can.

It's far easier to write unit tests for logic implemented in java.

Comment: agreed but using trivial c:if can help you unburden the java code, which is at times more complex

Comment: You are better off keeping the burden where it is easy to maintain automated testing. Of course there will always be cases where the decision to render a chunk of the page must be made on the JSP itself.

Answer (score 0):

JSF JSTL and JSP JSTL are the same thing, so they perform the same. The only factor you need to consider is that a JSF JSTL expression may be evaluated up to six times as often.