# Thousands of PageContext instances cause OutOfMemoryError. Does the JSP Tag release the PageContext?

Tags: java, jsp, memory-leaks, jboss, jsp-tags

We are struggling from the Out Of Memory Error caused by overpopulated instances of `PageContextImpl` and `PerThreadTagHandlerPool$PerThreadData`.

The Memory Analyzer says that the main suspect is `PageContextImpl`:

> 12,874 instances of "org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl", loaded by "org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader @ 0x640015838" occupy 922,562,624 (21.53%) bytes.

Further investigation shows that the `PageContextImpl` instances are referenced from `javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport` (from `jboss-javaee-all-6.0-3.0.3.Final.jar`).

[image]

The `GetTag` class extends `javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport` which has fields

```
private Tag parent;
private Hashtable<String, Object> values;
protected String id;
protected PageContext pageContext;
```

From reading articles like this:

- [JSP tag lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/616064/2886891)
- [JSP Tag Pooling Memory Leaks](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2009/08/jsp-tag-pooling-memory-leaks-2/)
- [Memory Leak using custom JSP tags on JBoss as7](https://developer.jboss.org/message/635847#635847)

I suspect that we have an issue in a misunderstanding or a bug in the Custom Tag Lifecycle, however I cannot find the root cause. Maybe the answer is in one of these articles, but it seems like none of them describes the non-released `PageContext` instances.

Btw, our `PerThreadTagHandlerPool$PerThreadData` in memory are also highly overpopulated, exactly like described in the already mentioned [Memory Leak using custom JSP tags on JBoss as7](https://developer.jboss.org/message/635847#635847):

[image]

I understand that we may just disable the Tag pooling but I would like to find the root cause first.

Questions:

1. Do the *pooled* JSP Tags release the reference to `PageContext`?
2. Can you see any other cause of this memory leak?

Comment: What kind of tags are being used in here,like default JSP tags or some custom tags and does removing them,solve the issue?

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal: I believe that custom tags, I am not familiar with JSP, I was just asked to help a team with memory leak analysis. If they have their own tag classes I suppose it means they have custom tags, don't they? :) Removing them is out of question, it is a huge legacy code and we cannot touch it.

Comment: Okkay!Would have to dig in more in Tag handler pool stuff I suppose

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal: I am not sure if I understand your last comment. Maybe one thing should be mentioned and it is that the issues appeared after migration from WebLogic to JBoss.

Comment: I mean to say that TagPoolHandler could hold the answer to this may be,please update the migration detail in question and weblogic to tag as well for reaching bigger group

Comment: The way pagecontext and TagPoolHandler are interpreted by new server!

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal: I cannot answer your question without more explanation. Tell me what configuration data you want to know.

Comment: Sorry mate,not sure on what configs are messing this up.Was referring to dig more in how the tags are being dealt with by both servers